How to enable USB debugging mode when it has been disabled?
I have a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra running Android 14, which I am almost certain has malware/a rootkit on it.
I'd like to take a forensic image of the device.
In developer mode, the 'USB debugging' mode is shaded in and set to off. I don't know how to unshade it and set it to enabled.
How might this have happened and what can I do to get an image off of it?
